# Spring Micrometer: How to access tag related information

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer

Sorry for this stupid question, but I cannot understand how to extract tag-specific information from Micrometer.

We are using Spring Boot 2.7.6. When using multiple counters with tags like this:

```
private Map<String, Counter> errorCounters = new HashMap<>();

...

tenantList.forEach(tenant ->
{
    final Counter counter = Counter.builder("company.publishing_errors")
            .description("Total number of failed tries to publish an object.")
            .tag("tenant", tenant)
            .register(registry);
    errorCounters.put(tenant, counter);
});

...

errorCounters.get(tenant).increment();
```

which results in one counter per tenant. In the debugger I can clearly see that they are counted independently.

Under http://127.0.0.1:8080/actuator/metrics/company.publishing_errors I see the following JSON:

```
{
  "name":"company.publishing_errors",
  "description":"Total number of failed tries to publish an object.",
  "baseUnit":null,
  "measurements":[{
    "statistic":"COUNT",
    "value":6.0
  }],
  "availableTags":[{
    "tag":"tenant",
    "values":[
      "tenant1",
      "tenant2"
    ]}
  ]}
```

I tried multiple variations to extract the tag specific data, but failed. All tutorials and guides I found either stop at this point, or just import the data into e.g. Grafana which extracts the data itself. Do I have to specify the version, e.g. [Micrometer-Prometheus](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus)? We are only using the Spring Boot standard, which includes the `micrometer-core`-library. Do I need to set `commonTags`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to input from a colleague, I found the answer.

According to [the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.endpoint), you can view tag specific data with `tag=KEY:VALUE` query parameters. So in my case the URL would be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/actuator/metrics/company.publishing_errors?tag=tenant:tenant1
```